# Maven surefire plugin skipAfterFailureCount configuration not working

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I wanna stop test execution when one of them failed. I tried skipAfterFailureCount config in pom xml and ***mvn -Dsurefire.skipAfterFailureCount=1*** as a command line argument but still has no effect. Is there a clear way to do this ?

**PART OF MY POM.XML:**

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.22.2</version>
   <configuration>
     <skipAfterFailureCount>1</skipAfterFailureCount>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**I'm using JUnit 5.6.2**

Answer (score 8):

This feature is not yet supported for the JUnit5.

See the documentation
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/featurematrix.html

There is a feature request [SUREFIRE-1698](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1698) and another one [SUREFIRE-1710](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1710) which needs to be implemented in **JUnitPlatformProvider**. Feel free to contribute at the [Github](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/). You need to implement SPI for junit5's **ExecutionCondition** and maybe the **TestWatcher**.

Comment: Thanks for the responding, I know that a little bit late =)